# Redis server refused to connect while using docker image

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

i am using docker to start using postgres, kibana, elasticsearch and redis.(using docker-compose up command). However redis failed to start  giving this error.
[image]

You can see read the last error line in the screenshot(showing bad file format). How can i resolve this?
Also i dont know how to run redis commands in terminal using docker such as ./redis-check-aof --fix  as given in screenshot?

Comment: Can you please post your `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 7):

Like Uku mentions, the AOF file has become corrupted and you should run a command to fix it. The correct command for the official Redis `redis:4.0.11-alpine` image is:

```
docker-compose run redis redis-check-aof --fix appendonly.aof
```

This assumes the name of your redis container is "redis". Hit "y" to confirm (it's not phrased like a question but it needs that input.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add some additional information regarding this issue with a `redis:7` docker container after rebuilding a server from a snapshot.

- Redis stores append-only files in a dedicated directory, as defined by the [`appenddirname`](https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/) parameter in the config (defaults to `appendonlydir`).
- Running the docker compose command gives a dialog box which requires a `y/N` response (you don't actually see the `Continue [y/N]` after you've pressed a key; strange but true). After pressing `y` you will see a message that it's succesfully truncated.

```bash
$ docker compose run --rm -it redis redis-check-aof --fix /data/appendonlydir/appendonly.aof.18.incr.aof

Start checking Old-Style AOF
AOF /data/appendonlydir/appendonly.aof.18.incr.aof format error
AOF analyzed: filename=/data/appendonlydir/appendonly.aof.18.incr.aof, size=25858048, ok_up_to=25857792, ok_up_to_line=511436, diff=256
This will shrink the AOF /data/appendonlydir/appendonly.aof.18.incr.aof from 25858048 bytes, with 256 bytes, to 25857792 bytes
y
Continue? [y/N]: Successfully truncated AOF /data/appendonlydir/appendonly.aof.18.incr.aof
```

- If you try to fix it again after already being fixed, it (hopefully) shows the file being valid.

```bash
Start checking Old-Style AOF
AOF analyzed: filename=/data/appendonlydir/appendonly.aof.18.incr.aof, size=25857792, ok_up_to=25857792, ok_up_to_line=511436, diff=0
AOF /data/appendonlydir/appendonly.aof.18.incr.aof is valid
```

Then up your redis like normally, and if everything went well, you should have a working container again.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Your redis AOF file has become corrupted. Two options:

1) if you don't care about the data, you could just delete the volume and recreate it

2) if you do care about the data, temporarily add the entrypoint definition for redis service:

```
entrypoint:
 - redis-check-aof
 - --fix
 - /data/appendonly.aof
```

docker-compose up once, and then remove it, this should hopefully fix it

Comment: executed, showing "No container found for redis_1",  i never executed this command and  redis was working earlier, the connection refusing error started from yesterday.

Comment: can you specify a full command with entry point i need to execute on terminal?

Comment: add the line specified to your `docker-compose.yml`file into  `redis` section and run `docker-compose up` like normally

Comment: Confirmed, it says "invalid arguments" and kills the container